# can i calculate the value from the euler function for $60^{90}$ by breaking this number into prime factors?

Tags: totient-function

We can calculate the value of the phi function for the number $30^{90}$ as follows:

$\phi(30^{90})=\phi((2\cdot 5\cdot 3)^{90})=\phi(2^{90})\cdot \phi(5^{90})\cdot \phi(3^{90})=2^{89}\cdot(2-1)\cdot 5^{89}\cdot(5-1)\cdot 3^{89}\cdot(3-1)=2^{92}\cdot 5^{89}\cdot 3^{89}$

Can the same be done for $60^{90}$? When we broke down $30$ into prime factors, each of them was unique, whereas $60$ is different because there is another $2$. So the prime factors are not relatively prime to each other because $2$ is not relatively prime to $2$.

Comment: Well, sure.  Just write out the prime factorization of $60^{90}$...

Comment: @lulu I understand that $\phi(60^{90})=\phi((2\cdot 5\cdot 3\cdot 2)^{90})=\dots$ should give me right result. Thank

Comment: Write $60^{90}=2^{180}3^{90}5^{90}.$

Comment: It's clearer, I expect, if you write it as $\left(2^2\times 3\times 5\right)^{90}=2^{180}\times 3^{90}\times 5^{90}$.

Comment: @DScounterGO It is certainly thrue that $$\phi(60^{90})=\phi((2\cdot5\cdot 3\cdot 2)^{90}),$$ but it is not clear what you mean by "should give me the same result."

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I mean correct

Comment: You certainly can't compute $\phi(60^n)$ as $\phi(2^n)\phi(3^n)\phi(5^n)\phi(2^n).$

Comment: But how do you compute the second value? The second value isn't any clearer how to find the value than the first value, is it?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Good tip

Comment: In general, $\phi(m^n)=\phi(m)m^{n-1}.$ So the value will be $$\phi(60^{90})=\phi(60)60^{89}.$$

Comment: I would make mistake by computing that like you said. Now i know that i can absorb second $2$ to make $2^2$ before leaving function

Comment: More generally, if the distinct prime divisors of $m_1$ and $m_2$ are the same:  $$\frac{\phi(m_1)}{m_1}=\frac{\phi(m_2)}{m_2},$$ so if $m_1=30, m_2=60^{90},$ then: $$\phi(60^{90})=\frac{\phi(30)}{30}\cdot 60^{90}$$